# Is there a way to disable icon scaling in TTreeView

Tags: c++builder, vcl, c++builder-11-alexandria

I have assigned a 16x16 icons `TImageList` to a `TTreeView` object.

Same ImageList is also assigned to a `TListView`.

When I change the OS dpi setting to display everything at 150% (for instance), the text scales nicely, but so do the icons in the TreeView.

In the ListView the icons stay 16x16 however (same as a few other components).

To keep things uniform (until I implement more icons with different dimensions) is there a way to disable icon scaling in the TreeView ?

TreeView on the left (notice the icons stretched), ListView on the right (icons crisp):

[image: Icon scaling]

Comment: You probably need to paint the items your self then, either in `OnDrawItem()` or in `OnAdvancedDrawItem()` of the `TTreeView`.

Comment: You really should be using `TVirtualImageList` now when dealing with DPI. See [Supporting high-DPI images with the Image Collection and Virtual ImageList components](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Supporting_high-DPI_images_with_the_Image_Collection_and_Virtual_ImageList_components)

Comment: @TomBrunberg Yeah I feared so, I was hoping to avoid that in the interim

Comment: @RemyLebeau I found the link yesterday but thanks for the intel.  I was hoping to avoid that in the interim because it involves making more icons with different dimensions, but if there is no easy switch to turn icon scaling off for a `TTreeView` I will have to look into this sooner than later indeed.

Comment: You can't "turn off" the scaling, unless you take over the drawing yourself. I'd be more concerned with why `TTreeView` and `TListView` are scaling differently. That sounds more like a bug that should be [reported to Embarcadero](https://quality.embarcadero.com). They still have a lot of DPI issues they are working through.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, yes, I was wondering about that too :-)  Perhaps I should report it indeed.

Comment: Reported: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-36979
The issue is also related to the TreeView being a descendant of `TTreeView'.  It's the only situation where the icon scales